# Generating the release APK

Tags: react-native

while Generating the release APK it gives error:

Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\root\React_Native\rncourse\node_modules (83ms)
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\root\React_Native\rncourse\node_modules (108ms)
Loading dependency graph, done.
warning: the transform cache was reset.
bundle: Writing bundle output to: C:\root\React_Native\rncourse\android\app\build\intermediates\assets\release\index.android.bundle
bundle: Done writing bundle output
bundle: Copying 4 asset files
bundle: Done copying assets

C:\root\React_Native\rncourse\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\drawable-mdpi\src_assets_logopng.png: error: uncompiled PNG file passed as argument. Must be compiled first into .flat file..
error: failed parsing overlays.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.

  > Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: "error: uncompiled PNG file passed as argument. Must be compiled first into .flat file.. error: failed parsing overlays."

Answer (score 0):

For a workaround solution you can add this line to your `android/gradle.properties` file:

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

but as I said, it's a workaround and is deprecated.

I didn't find a complete solution for this but if I do find a better solution, I'll edit my answer!

Comment: i add android.enableAapt2=false to android/gradle.properties and its run successfully.

Comment: But  while Testing the release build apk its stuck on splash screen.App works well on AVD.When installing the signed Apk on real device, get stuck on splash screen. if press back and open the app again  app doesn't get open just flashes.

Comment: @AniruddhaBhamare I know it's wierd but maybe this link will help you: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/4755

Comment: solve :edit android/app/build.gradle
   project.ext.react = [  entryFile: "index.js"
]    entryFile:"index.android.js"

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can do to avoid this error
 1. You can try with delete build folder and make a new release build
 2. try deleting android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\drawable-mdpi in your project
 may be these points avoids your problem